# Running python file from command prompt ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'

Tags: python, pygame, modulenotfounderror

I have this error when running the script from terminal but works from `PyCharm`

```
C:\Users\Username\PycharmProjects\Space Invaders>python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

This is how my file directory looks:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9qB5.png

I am using `python 3.8` and `pygame 2.0.1`

Should I have to install pygame globally for me to run the script from command line? I have the package installed in a virtual environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to execute the script with global python which doesn't have the pygame package installed. So, you have to activate the virtual environment first. To do this, go to venv/Scripts/ and there will be an "activate" file that you need to execute. Once you have done this you can run your script and it should work.

More info on: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html